tabindex on button within MatMenu in angular not working
I am using material in my angular 17 project. I want to add ADA compliance in my project and for that adding tabindex wherever necessary.
Problem i am facing is, i have button in mat menu and tabindex="0" is not putting focus on button within MatMenu. Below is my code. Please let me know how can i add focus on button within MatMenu.
.ts
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';

@ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) menuTrigger!: MatMenuTrigger;

openMenu(event:Event):void{
    event.preventDefault();
    this.menuTrigger.openMenu();
  }

.html
<div tabindex="0" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (keydown.enter)="openMenu($event)">OPEN DIV</div>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" class="menu-popover">    
    <div class="popover-text">Are you sure you want to edit this?</div>
    Test Menu
    <button tabindex="0">Close</button>
  </mat-menu>


I can’t recall the StackOverflow tag for the Americans with Disabilities Act, but it’s not [ada]

I think we are missing the directive for the button mat-menu-item, working example below!
<button
  mat-button
  [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
  (keydown.enter)="openMenu($event);button.focus();"
  (keydown.tab)="$event.stopPropagation();"
  (menuOpened)="button.focus();"
>
  Menu
</button>
<!-- #enddocregion mat-menu-trigger-for -->
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" tabindex="0">
  <button mat-menu-item tabindex="0" #button (keydown)="buttonKeyDown($event)">
    Item 1
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item tabindex="0" (keydown)="buttonKeyDown($event)">
    Item 2
  </button>
</mat-menu>

Stackblitz Demo

Thank you for sharing the code.I notice one thing and want to confirm. When i click tab, it correctly opens the modal. And then buttons within modal are focused using UP and DOWN arrow and not TAB key. Is it the ADA standard for modal that within modals, buttons should be focused with UP and DOWN keys and not the tab keys ?

@farazch From technical perspective only I know, but I am not an expert on ADA but you can use aria-label to inform the user on the accessibility might help them, this is just a suggestion and in no means the correct solution, plz wait for someone else to give their advice on this question! aria label docs for mat menu

right. I checked, this need to be worked with tabs and not UP and DOWN keys to meet ADA standard.
